# How to run function with toggle/switch fbutton correctly

Tags: jquery

i've created a toggle button that changes prices to annual and working fine but the problem is that when user click it twice it will multiply the value again (not back to the monthly price);

html .

`<div class="total" name="total" id="total"> $0</div>`

jquery

```
$("#toggle").click(function() { 

      $("#total").toggleClass("total", 500).promise().done(function() {

      var tlt = $("#total").text().replace("$","");

      var tlt_price = parseFloat(tlt);

      var min_price = tlt_price - 1;

      var tlt_n = min_price * 12;

      $(".total").html(tlt_n);



    });   

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues, but the main issue is that you're using the display and data interchangeably, which is wrong.  Every time you click the toggle, it pulls the displayed value and converts it again.

For starters, I would suggest using the data attribute to store the base value.

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Something like this:

```
<div class="total" data-total="0" name="total" id="total"> $0</div>
```

Then you can pull the data like so...

```
var tlt = $("#total").data("total");
```

This way you only pull the data to start the conversion, and when you update the text, the data attribute will remain the same.

The other major issue is that you toggle the class name, but only do a one way conversion.  In the callback, you should check if the `total` class exists, and convert to annual or monthly based on that.

You can check the toggle status with `hasClass` like so.

```
$("#total").hasClass("total")
```

Comment: Actually i couldn't set data-total because i've to get the value user enter its gonna show there. the major problem i'm facing now is that, its not going back to what it was with second click on toggle button. can you please help me with that?

Comment: Is there any other way to do what i want?

Comment: You need to preserve the original data.  You can set the data attribute whenever you wait.  Since you're displaying the data in a div, at some point you need to show the data the user entered, you can set the data attribute then or you can even set it the first time a toggle is done.  You can check to see if data has a value if not then set it.